# NET MAUI SecureStorage GetAsync not returning the value and no exception

Tags: c#, maui

I am playing with net maui on Android emulator.
I have created a wrapper around the SecureStorage:

```
public static class StorageService
{
        public static async Task SaveAsync<T>(string key, T data)
        {
            var value = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            await SecureStorage.Default.SetAsync(key, value);
        }

        public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                var value = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(key);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    return (T)default;

                var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
                return data;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return (T)default;
            }
        }

        public static bool Remove(string key)
        {
            return SecureStorage.Default.Remove(key);
        }

        public static void RemoveAll()
        {
            SecureStorage.Default.RemoveAll();
        }
}
```

On the login page, when I press the login button I receive the response from the server and I store the response in the SecureStorage

```
private async void LoginClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = await securityClient.LoginAsync(viewModel);

    if (response is null)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("", "Login faild, or unauthorized", "OK");
        StorageService.Secure.Remove(StorageKeys.Secure.JWT);
        return;
    }

    await StorageService.Secure.SaveAsync<JWTokenModel>(StorageKeys.Secure.JWT, response);

    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(PageRoutes.HomePage, true);
    }
```

No errors, and I got redirected to the HomePage.
The MainPage constructor (bellow) get called and the DI kick in trying to create an instance of the clients.

```
    public MainPage(IPlayerClient playerClient, IPositionClient positionClient, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
            this.playerClient = playerClient;
            this.positionClient = positionClient;
            this.memoryCache = memoryCache;
    
            SubScribeOnDelte();
}
    
    public class PlayerClient : BaseClient, IPlayerClient
    {
        public PlayerClient(HttpClient httpClient, MobileAppSettings settings) : base(httpClient, settings)
        {}
    }
    
    public class PositionClient : BaseClient, IPositionClient
    {
        public PositionClient(HttpClient httpClient, MobileAppSettings settings) : base(httpClient, settings)
        {
        }
    }
```

I the process it calls the base class constructor where I setup up the httpClient.

```
public abstract class BaseClient : IAsyncInitialization
{
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private readonly MobileAppSettings settings;

    public Task Initialization { get; private set; }

    private string BaseURL
    {
        get
        {
            return DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ?
                                          this.settings.AndroidBaseURL : 
                                          this.settings.IosBaseURL;
        }
    }

    protected BaseClient(HttpClient httpClient, MobileAppSettings settings)
    {
        this.settings = settings;

        Initialization = InitializeAsync(httpClient);
    }

    private async Task InitializeAsync(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = await BuildHttpClient(httpClient);
    }

    private async Task<HttpClient> BuildHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
#if DEBUG
        var handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();
        httpClient = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler());
#endif

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURL);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "amazonsofvolleyball");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new("application/json"));

        var jwt = await StorageService.Secure.GetAsync<JWTokenModel>(StorageKeys.Secure.JWT);
        if(jwt is not null)
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt.Token);

        return httpClient;
    }

}
```

But when it hits the StorageService GetAsync(string key) method, the line

```
var value = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(key);
```

did not return anything, no exception, and my injected httpClient stays null (obiously there are some kind of error), and it continues with the DI and try to create a new instance for the next interface where the same happens.

I set in the AndroidManifest.xml  file the recommended setting"
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... >

Comment: This might or might not fix: You've called an `async` method from the constructor, which is NOT an `await` context. VIsual Studio should show a WARNING on the line `Initialization = InitializeAsync(httpClient);`. DO NOT IGNORE such a warning. Start the sequence of calls from an `await` context. Try `Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () => Initialization = await InitializeAsync(...);`  If you need more info, search for previous c# discussions of calling `async` method from constructor.